# receiving error message when writing powershell script for installing software

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to write a script to install software.  The script is below:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter The Computer Name"
$Software = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter The Software Name"
switch ($Software)
{
    Java {$Software = "C:\Script\Java.msi"}
    Atom {$Software = "C:\Script\AtomSetup.exe"}
    Notepad {$Software = "C:\Script\notepad.exe"}
    Default {Throw No Software Match found for $software}
}
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Copy-Item -Path $Software -Destination C:\Script -Recurse -Verbose -ToSession $session
$session | Remove-PSSession
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {start-process -Filepath $software -ArgumentList '/silent' -wait 
Remove-Item -Path $software -Force
}
```

I am getting the error message below.

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : testPC
>
> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : testPC

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `Default {Throw "No Software Match found for $software"}` (missing double quotes). Read and follow [about_Throw:THROWING A STRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw?view=powershell-6#throwing-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow [**Invoke-Command** docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.0#parameters):

> **`-ArgumentList`**
>
> Supplies the values of local variables in the command. The variables
>   in the command are replaced by these values before the command is run
>   **on the remote computer**. Enter the values in a comma-separated list.
>   Values are associated with variables in the order that they are
>   listed. The alias for *ArgumentList* is *Args*.
>
> The values in the *ArgumentList* parameter can be actual values, such
>   as 1024, or they can be references to local variables, such as `$max`.
>
> To use local variables in a command, use the following command format:
>
> ```
> {param($<name1>[, $<name2>]...) <command-with-local-variables>} -ArgumentList <value> -or- <local-variable>
> ```
>
> The `param` keyword lists the local variables that are used in the
>   command. *ArgumentList* supplies the values of the variables, in the
>   order that they are listed.

Use

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential (Get-Credential) `
    -ScriptBlock {
        param($Software)
        Start-Process -Filepath $software -ArgumentList '/silent' -wait 
        Remove-Item -Path $software -Force
    } -ArgumentList $Software
```

Comment: i did like you instructed. I am receiving this error message. This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified. + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand + PSComputerName : testPC